# Classifying curve shapes

Tags: python, classification

I need to classify 40,000 curves (available in graph and numerical format) into these three known shapes below.

I'm thinking about using three shape metrics (the minimum, maximum and the integral) for the classification.

Each curve is saved as a pandas Series with re-sampled x,y values (x values at regular intervals with re-sampled y-values).

Any Python module I can use?

[image]

Comment: Please describe more about the numerical format of the graphs.

Comment: Each curve is saved as a pandas Series with re-sampled x,y values (x values at regular intervals with re-sampled y-values)

Comment: So it seems reasonable to use a simple Logistic regression model to classify those graphs. I think it's not easy for the first time to get familiar with new concepts but it will be useful for you afterward https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/deep_learning_tutorial.html

Comment: Doesn't a logistic regression model estimate against two outcomes only (0 or 1)? In my case, I have three possible outcomes (the shape class) for each curve.

Comment: Multi class classification can help in the problem.